# Merging two tables into one in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have two tables, each with many attributes.  There are attributes that I want from each, and I am trying to write a query to get those attributes, and put them into three columns.

Table A

```
LOCATION_NUMBER (varchar2(20Byte)), 
BEGIN (NUMBER (3,0)), 
BEGIN_DEC (NUMBER (4,3)), 
END (NUMBER (3,0)), 
END_DEC (NUMBER (4,3))
```

Table B

```
LOCNUM (NUMBER (15,0)), 
START (VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)), 
START_POS (NUMBER (5,3)), 
FINISH (VARCHAR2 (6 BYTE)), 
FINISH_POS (NUMBER (5,3)).
```

What I want from the query is one table, with three attributes and then order these tables by the location first, and start second.

Table C,

```
LOCATION, 
START, 
END
```

Here's an example:

A:

```
LOCATION_NUMBER    BEGIN    BEGIN_DEC    END    END_DEC
      I 26          8          0.63       13      0.99
      I 32          144        0          151     0.82
      I 35          22         0.29       55      0.09
      I 35          128        0.1        67      0.9
      I 35          0          0          22      0.28
```

B:

```
LOC_NUM            START    START_POS    FINISH  FINSIH_POS
      227           98         0.56       100     0
      35            149        0.25       151     0.55
      96            156        0.23       156     1.26
      11            263        2.56       263     4.52
```

RESULT SET:

```
LOCATION       START        END
    26          8.63         13.99
    32          144          151.82
    35          22.29        55.09
    35          128.1        67.9
    35          0            22.28   
    227         98.56        100
    35          149.25       151.55
    96          156.23       157.26
    11          265.56       267.52
```

I have some queries that I tried I am able to get the desired results from each table, I just need to know how to combine them into one to make things easier for what I want the table for, again, each of the tables have 10 - 20 more attributes that I don't want to worry about.

```
Select to_number(trim(regexp_substr(A.LOCATION_NUMBER ,'[^ ]+', 1, 2))) AS LOCATION,
(to_number(trim(A.BEGIN)) + to_number(trim(A.BEGIN_DEC))) AS START,
(to_number(trim(A.END)) + to_number(trim(A.END_DEC))) AS END
FROM A
ORDER BY to_number(trim(regexp_substr(A.LOCATION_NUMBER,'[^ ]+', 1, 2)));

SELECT B.LOC_NUM AS LOCATION,
(to_number(trim(B.START)) + to_number(trim(B.START_POS))) AS START,
(to_number(trim(B.FINISH)) + to_number(trim(B.FINISH_POS))) AS END
FROM B
ORDER BY B.LOCATION, START;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your queries work, you just want `union all`:

```
Select to_number(trim(regexp_substr(A.LOCATION_NUMBER ,'[^ ]+', 1, 2))) AS LOCATION,
       to_number(trim(A.BEGIN)) + to_number(trim(A.BEGIN_DEC)) AS START,
       to_number(trim(A.END)) + to_number(trim(A.END_DEC)) AS END
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.LOC_NUM AS LOCATION,
       to_number(trim(B.START)) + to_number(trim(B.START_POS)) AS START,
       to_number(trim(B.FINISH)) + to_number(trim(B.FINISH_POS)) AS END
FROM B
ORDER BY B.LOCATION, START;
```

Comment: Thank you! that did what I want I think.  Is that the most efficient way to do it? these tables could have 1000+records in them.

Comment: @user2217874 . . . If you want efficiency, store numbers as numbers not strings.  But I wouldn't worry about a few thousand records, unless your computer is more than 15 years old.